# ¿cuales son los usos correctos de contains; equals; e ==? para comparar objetos, Integers, Int, Strings..?

Tags: java

¿cuales son los usos correctos de contains; equals; e ==? para comparar objetos, Integers, Int, Strings..? Se que a veces se pueden usar de forma equivocada pero no se bien .. Gracias

Answer (score 4):

En Java, `==` solo compara dos referencias (no primitivas), es decir, prueba si los dos operandos se refieren al mismo objeto.

Sin embargo, el método `equals` puede ser anulado, por lo que dos objetos distintos pueden ser iguales.

Por ejemplo:

```
String x = "hello";
String y = new String(new char[] { 'h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o' });

System.out.println(x == y); // false
System.out.println(x.equals(y)); // true
```

Además, vale la pena tener en cuenta que dos constantes de cadena iguales (principalmente literales de cadena, pero también combinaciones de constantes de cadena mediante concatenación) terminarán refiriéndose a la misma cadena.

Por ejemplo:

```
String x = "hello";
String y = "he" + "llo";
System.out.println(x == y); // true!
```

Aquí `x` & `y` hacen referencias a la misma cadena, porque `y` es una constante en tiempo de compilación igual a `"hello"`.

Otro Ejemplo:

```
Integer i = 100;
Integer p = 100;
if (i == p)  System.out.println("i y p son lo mismo.");
if(i.equals(p))  System.out.println("i y p contienen el mismo valor.");
```

En Cambio si es asi:

```
Integer i = new Integer (100); 
Integer p = new Integer (100); 
if (i == p) System.out.println("i y p son el mismo objeto"); 
if (i.equals(p)) System.out.println("i y p contienen el mismo valor");
```

> Fuente SO:
>
> - [What's the difference between “.equals” and “==”?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1643079/8933039).
> - [Immutable Objects / Wrapper Class Caching](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Java_gotchas#Immutable_Objects_.2F_Wrapper_Class_Caching).

---

**Contains()**:

Sobre el método [`Contains()`](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/lang/string_contains.htm) este comprueba si una cadena en particular es una parte de otra cadena o no.

> Devuelve verdadero si y solo si esta cadena contiene la secuencia especificada de valores de `char`.

Ejemplo:

```
String[] arreglo= new String[] { "Lunes", "Martes" };
String valor= Arrays.toString(arreglo);
boolean resultado = string.contains("Martes");
```

Pero yo recomendaría:

```
String[] arreglo= new String[] { "Lunes", "Martes" };
List<String> lista= Arrays.asList(arreglo);
boolean resultado = stringList.contains("Martes");
```

> Ver:  [Arrays # asList (T ...)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#asList(T...)) y [ArrayList # contains (Object)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#contains(java.lang.Object))