# Comparacion con Equals

Tags: java

Este codigo funciona bien pero no logro comprender su funcionamiento, no sabia como realizar la pregunta, por que no tengo que resolver nada solo entenderlo.
El codigo esta sacado de una clase Punto que tiene dos atributos(x,y).

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (this == obj)
        return true;//
    if (obj == null)
        return false;
    if (!(obj instanceof Punto))
        return false;
    Punto other = (Punto) obj;//aqui ya no entiendo nada
    if (Double.doubleToLongBits(x) != Double.doubleToLongBits(other.x))
        return false;
    if (Double.doubleToLongBits(y) != Double.doubleToLongBits(other.y))
        return false;
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Y cual es tu pregunta? o el problema que te presenta?

Comment: A ese  `obj` que recibe el método por parámetro lo esta convirtiendo en `Punto` en esta linea: `Punto other = (Punto) obj;` Para Luego obtener a  `x` & `y`

Comment: 1ª  No se por que esta @override.     2º  no se por que necesita convertirlo a punto.

Comment: ` @override` Esto es porque el método `equals` es un método propio del lenguaje y le estas indicando al `IDE` que estas sobrescribiendo el método para realizar tu tarea especifica dentro de ese método, deberias leer esto: [java override y encapsulacion](https://www.arquitecturajava.com/java-override-y-encapsulacion/), necesitas convertirlo a `Punto` porque el objeto que recibe como tal es tipo `Object` y puede que no cuente con las mismas propiedad que el tipo `Punto` en este caso, cada tipo de objeto tiene sus método y propiedades, y muchas son comunes entre los objetos.

Comment: Más detalles aqui: [¿Para que sirve la línea @Override en java?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/156457/69447)

Comment: Ya entiendo mejor la anotacion @override,                    if (this == obj)   Otra pregunta ¿this se refiere a que si todos sus atributos son los mismos  del objeto que  llega por parametro?    y otra mas ¿ por que  transforma el numero en  con doubleToLongBits?

Comment: No, no se refiere a que los atributos son iguales, `if (this == object)` aquí esta preguntando si el objeto actual y el recibido por parámetro son iguales pero a nivel de objeto no de propiedades, y sobre `doubleToLongBits` Respuesta corta: Eclipse usa [Double.doubleToLongBits](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#doubleToLongBits%28double%29) porque eso es lo que hace [Double.equals](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29)

Comment: `if (this == object)` lo que hace es comparar si la referencia que hay en `object` apunta a la misma instancia `this`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Ya que la conversación en los comentarios ha avanzado debido a sus diferentes preguntas, trataré de darle una respuesta general aquí.*

**No se por que esta `@override`:**

`@override` Esto es porque el método `equals` es un método propio del lenguaje y le estas indicando al `IDE` que estas sobrescribiendo el método para realizar tu tarea especifica dentro de ese método.

Para mas información respecto a `@override`:

> - [¿Para que sirve la línea @Override en java?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/156457/69447)

---

**No entiendo esto:**

```
Punto other = (Punto) obj;
```

A ese `obj` que recibe el método por parámetro lo esta convirtiendo en un tipo `Punto`, para luego obtener a `x` & `y`.

---

**`if (this == obj)` ¿this se refiere a que si todos sus atributos son los mismos del objeto que llega por parametro?**

No, no se refiere a que los atributos son iguales, `if (this == obj)` aquí `==` compara referencias de objetos, comprueba si los dos operandos apuntan al mismo objeto (no objetos equivalentes , **el mismo objeto**).

> Vea esto para más información:
>
> - [¿cuales son los usos correctos de contains; equals; e ==? para comparar objetos, Integers, Int, Strings..?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/163835/69447)

---

**¿Por que transforma el número con `doubleToLongBits`?:**

Respuesta corta: Eclipse usa [Double.doubleToLongBits](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#doubleToLongBits%28double%29) porque eso es lo que hace [Double.equals](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29):

> El resultado es `true` si y solo si el argumento no es `null` y es un objeto `double` que representa un `double` que tiene el mismo valor que el `double` representado por este objeto. Para este propósito, dos valores `double` se consideran iguales si y solo si el método `doubleToLongBits(double)` devuelve el mismo valor `long` cuando se aplica a cada uno.

Respuesta larga: el JLS especifica algunas diferencias entre `Double.equals` y `==`. Para una diferencia especificada en [JLS 4.2.3](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.2.3) y [JLS 15.21.1](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.21.1):

El cero positivo y el cero negativo se comparan iguales; por lo tanto, el resultado de la expresión  `0.0==-0.0` es `true` y el resultado de `0.0>-0.0` es `false`. Pero otras operaciones pueden distinguir cero positivo y negativo; por ejemplo, `1.0/0.0` tiene el valor infinito positivo, mientras que el valor de `1.0/-0.0` es infinito negativo.

Otro respeto `NaN`:

> Si cualquiera de los operandos es `NaN`, entonces el resultado de `==` es `false` pero el resultado de `!=` es `true`.
>
> De hecho, la prueba `x!=x` es `true` si y solo si el valor de `x` es `NaN`.

Como puede ver, **es posible comparar dos valores dobles, `==` pero en realidad corresponden a comportamientos diferentes cuando se usan en tablas matemáticas y `hash`**. Por lo tanto, cuando se escribe un método de igualdad generado, Eclipse asume que dos dobles solo son iguales si y solo si todas las operaciones que se les pueden hacer son idénticas, o (equivalentemente) si se autoboxan y se comparan con sus métodos `equals`. Esto es particularmente importante si se cambia entre `double` y `Double`, sería particularmente inesperado que las propiedades de igualdad difieran allí.

Por supuesto, usted es libre de desviarse de esa suposición: independientemente de si es una buena idea, puede asignar casos especiales a cualquiera de las muchas posibles representaciones de `NaN`, en cuyo caso [`Double.doubleToRawLongBits()`](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/lang/double_doubletolongbits.htm) sería una mejor coincidencia para su `equals`.

> Fuente SO: [Meaning of Double.doubleToLongBits(x)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23439003/8933039)